# android: how to find the location of form widget or imageview?

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, android-linearlayout

In my application, i'm drag & drop my textview, imageview from one Linear Layout to another one.How can i find the current location of textview or imageview whether it is first Layout or Second Layout programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the view parent by calling `view.getParent()`, and then casting it to `LinearLayout`. Then, i'd just check the parent id with `view.getId()` and check if it equals `R.id.nameOfYourFirstLayout` or `R.id.nameOfYourSecondLayout`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to retrive the parent view and check the Id of it:

```
View parent = (View)view.getParent();
```

or are the layouts also dynamic?